# Figure appears at bottom of page despite [H] option

Tags: floats

I start a new section on a new page and want to show an image first. I use the figure-environment because it needs a caption, and the [H] option because otherweise Latex places it god knows where.

Yet, the graphic appears at the bottom of the page, not immediately after the header of the section. How to prevent this?

```
\subsection{Gefaltetes Netz(cnn)}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{pictures/nets/cnn.eps}
    \caption{Netzmodell: Gefaltetes Netz}
    \label{net:cnn}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\begin{figure}[h]` with lowercase h

Comment: With the information you have provided this is not reproducible. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the shown behaviour and enables us to reproduce it.

Comment: What follows this `figure` with the `[H]` float specifier?

Comment: I presume you have `\usepackage{float}` at your preamble.

Answer (score 2):

you have not provided any code to reproduce the problem but `[H]` means the figure will not move it will be positioned exactly as a letter or box at that position will be positioned.

Presumably you have `\flushbottom` in effect and the only stretch space on that page is after the section head so it has to stretch that space to put ensure that there is no space at the bottom of the page.

So you could use `\raggedbottom` or note the reason that latex floats figures is to avoid getting ugly white space at page breaks so by using `[H]` and disabling floats you shoudl expect to get bad space unless you make manual corrections, for example arranging the following text that you did not show so that it fits on to that page under the figure.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the document class and the packages used 
I think that the issue can be fixed by replacing `\begin{figure}[H]` by `\begin{figure}[h]` .

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Gefaltetes Netz(cnn)}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{pictures/nets/cnn.eps}
    \caption{Netzmodell: Gefaltetes Netz}
    \label{net:cnn}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As sugested by @David Carlisle here is the same code in which I have replaced `\begion{figure}[h]` by `\begin{figure}[H]`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Gefaltetes Netz(cnn)}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{pictures/nets/cnn.eps}
    \caption{Netzmodell: Gefaltetes Netz}
    \label{net:cnn}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the output is totally different

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Gefaltetes Netz(cnn)}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Netzmodell: Gefaltetes Netz}
    \label{net:cnn}
\end{figure}

\section{Zzzz}

    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height=.7\textheight]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is unlikely to solve the OPs problem as stretching the space means that it is using `\flushbottom` but this example is using `\raggedbottom`, and also the implicit `\clearpage` at `\end{document}` both of which mean that whte space in the page will not stretch.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your interest! I don't understand why this is unlikely to solve the problem since it seems to me that what is needed is a figure placed just after the `\subsection` title

Comment: take your example, and use `[H]` after adding the `float` package and you will see that the `[H]` float comes exactly as you show with `h`. You need an example where `[H]` comes at the bottom of the page and [h]` does not, but that might be hard to find. (Also you should never use `[h]`, LaTeX usually warns about that and changes it to `[ht]`.)

Comment: Hi@DavidCarlisle I have updated my answer where I followed your suggestion. As you can see the position of the float has changed.

Comment: But the code example is the same. Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Sorry but I really don't understand! You said in your comment "take your example, and use [H] after adding the float package and you will see that the [H] float comes exactly as you show with h".

please be patient with me!

Comment: Both examples are the same. They should produce the same output. If you change the second example to include package `float` (which is needed to use `H`) you will still get the same output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since in the OP it is not mentionned that  the `float` package is or is not used my suggestion was to not use the  `float` package and to replace H with h. Is that wrong?

Comment: yes it is wrong. as if you get that big space with `[H]` you will most likely also get it with `[h]` and in anycase using `[h]` rather than say `[htp]` is almost always wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got it. thank  you very much for your useful explanations

Comment: as you can not add code in comments I added an example that generates the OPs original problem, as you will see changing `[H]` to `[h]` in that example changes the layout a bit but does not put the figure close to the heading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle does the problem still exist if you change the document class from book to article ?

Comment: with article you need `\flushbottom` as it defaults to `\raggedbottom`  otherwise the problem this question is asking about will not arise. (as I mentioned in the first comment above:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you think that with the `article` document class  the problem does not  arise  without `\flushbottom` even if the `float` package is not loaded?

Thank you once again for your patience!

Comment: to get the image shown in the question, you need flushbottom and a large unbreakable box of some sort on the following page. Why else would the space appear after a section heading? Clearly the OP is using float package as the code in the question uses `[H]` but that isn't that relevant, `[h]` is essentially the same thing here.